# pydicom module not found by python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, anaconda, pydicom

The error message:

In [1]:

```
import pydicom as dicomio
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-102814c2908e> in <module>()
----> 1 import pydicom as dicomio

ImportError: No module named pydicom
```

To install pydicom I used

```
conda skeleton pypi pydicom
conda build pydicom
```

Then uploaded to binstar and used conda install -c to download and install it again. It can now be seen in the anaconda environment.

```
Lindas-iMac:~ iMacLinda$ conda list -e | grep pydi
pydicom=0.9.9=py27_0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pydicom package is importable as `dicom` until version 0.9.9. The [documentation](https://pydicom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on read the docs is for the unreleased master branch version 1.0, in which the package name has changed to `pydicom`.

Thus, try importing pydicom as:

```
import dicom
```

If you need to read a file, you can use the command:

```
ds = dicom.read_file('filename.dcm')
```

Once pydicom 1.0 is released, you can follow the [wiki page](https://github.com/darcymason/pydicom/wiki/Porting-to-pydicom-1.0) for porting instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can us `pip`:

```
pip install pydicom
```

Conda works with pip.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it did not work. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Did `pip` actually install it?

Comment: This is what happened.                                                                          Lindas-iMac:~ iMacLinda$ pip install pydicom
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pydicom in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: I have now done 'conda uninstall pydicom'. Then 'pip uninstall pydicom', Then 'pip install pydicom'. I got a message saying install successful. I can now see pydicom if I do 'conda list', but not if I use the option '-e'.  Python still cannot see the module.

Comment: The `-e` is just for exporting the package list. This does not work with pip-installed packages. Does `pydicom` import in Python now?

Answer (score 1):

If you use pydicom version < 1.0 then you should use `import dicom`. But if you use pydicom version >= 1.0 then you should install dicom first, then you can `import pydicom`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your reply Mike.

The information published at http://www.pydicom.readthedocs.org seems to be incorrect.
I have just found some alternative documentation at http://www.pyscience.wordpress.com 
Pydicom can be imported within python as dicom and not as pydicom:

```
>>>import dicom as dicomio
```

This seemed to work.

Comment: first link is rotten